# Swing - JPanel background color disappears

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent, mouse-listeners

I'm trying to draw inside my JPanel but everytime I click, the background of my JPanel disappears. It draws a line where the mouse is. I think it has something to do with the 2D graphics
Can someone help?

```
public Brush() {

addMouseListener(this);
    addMouseMotionListener(this);
    setBackground(Color.white);


 }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        Graphics2D g2;
       // super.paintComponent(g);

        g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2.setColor(brushColor);
       g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(8, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL));
        //Ellipse2D.Double circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(p1.x,p1.y,20,20);

        g2.fillOval(p1.x,p1.y,20,20);

        }


        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            dragging = true;
            p1 = e.getPoint();
            repaint();
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            dragging = false;
            p1 = e.getPoint();
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            if (dragging) {
                p1 = e.getPoint();
                repaint();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Always call the `super.paintComponent(g)` method inside of your override.

You're drawing wrong then. If you want to draw a bunch of ovals, then either

- create a collection of them and draw them with a for loop in paintComponent, or
- draw them in a BufferedImage which is then drawn in your paintComponent method.
- If I want to draw a curve with the mouse, I usually create an `ArrayList<Point>` and draw lines between contiguous points, either in paintComponent or in a BufferedImage.

---

Again, your code is written to draw **only one point (oval actually)** within paintComponent. If coded correctly, this is all it will do.

I suggest, the easiest thing to do is:

- Give you class an `ArrayList<Point>`
- Add points when mouse is pressed and call repaint
- In `paintComponent`, call the super method, and then use a for loop to iterate through the ArrayList.
- Start the loop at the Point at item 1, not 0, and then draw a line between the previous Point and the current point.
- To get fancier, you may wish to have an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Point>>` where you start a new `ArrayList<Point>` with each press of the mouse, finish it with each release and add it to the overall collection. This will allow several lines to be drawn.

Why not give this a go on your own first?

Comment: But when I do that, the drawed ovals dissapear?

Comment: I don't understand, do you've got an example?
I also want that the points are drawed directly so not after you've released the mouse button

Comment: @RafVandelaer: see next edit. And search this site as there are already many examples of this, some written by me.

Comment: @RafVandelaer: ?? That doesn't make sense. You're already setting the Stroke. If you want a thicker line, why not just use a thicker stroke?